# API яндекс карт rest controller

Tags: java, yandex-maps-api, rest, яндекс-карты

Всем привет.
Есть такая задача. 
Необходимо разработать REST контроллер, который будет принимать на вход XML с параметрами (POST), получать данные из БД через разработанные репозитории, и формировать в ответе xml объект, который будет содержать ссылку на страницу с картой.

Хотелось бы посмотреть примеры или описание api методов и сущностный используемых в  Яндекс картах на java.

я что то только с js у них на сайте нашел.

всем спасибо

Comment: А что вам нужно со стороны API Карт? Из вашего вопроса получается, что нужна только ссылка на Яндекс.Карты, но для этого API не нужен.

Comment: вы верно заметили. Но у меня такая задача. 1) Сервис который я разрабатываю  получает POST запрос, по параметрам происходит получение координат и других данных, которые необходимо. (вот мне и нужно почитать про этот api чтобы понять что еще необходимо) 2) Сервис Генерирует HTML страницу, которая содержит все необходимое для отображения Яндекс.Карт с указанными параметрами.

Comment: всё равно не очень понятно - при желании вы можете генерировать html-страницу с интерактивной картой, для этого надо использовать js api Карт. Для создания карты достаточно указать центр и желаемый уровень масштаба. Можно добавить что-то ещё по желанию, но это зависит от вашей фантазии и того, что есть в БД, но это внутренняя кухня, которая не повлияет на генерацию карты.